# Quasar framework v-on:input does nothing

Tags: events, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a simple search input in Quasar app, which should listen on input event. But it does not. The code looks like:

```
<template>
    <div id="searchWrapper">
        <div class="row justify-center flex-direction q-px-lg-md">
            <h1 class="col-sm-6">StarWars search</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="search" class="row justify-center flex-direction q-px-lg-md">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <q-input outlined v-model="search" v-on:input="searchPeople" name="search" label="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-center flex-direction ">
            <q-list v-if="searchStatus == 'success'" bordered separator class="col-sm-6">
                <q-item v-for="item in searchResult" :key="item.id" clickable v-ripple>
                    <q-item-section>{{item.name}}</q-item-section>
                </q-item>
            </q-list>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { api } from 'boot/axios';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'PageIndex',

    data() {
        return {
            search: "",
            searchResult: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Luke',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Lea',
                }
            ],
            loading: false,
        }
    },
    ...

    methods: {
        searchPeople() {
            console.log('teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest');
            this.loading = true;
            api.get('https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people?search' + this.search)
                .then( result => {
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .catch( error => {

                })
                .then( () => {
                    this.loading = false
                });
            },
    },


})
</script>
```

I dont see console.log('teeeeeeeeeeeeest') nor the error. Nothing. Native Vue @input works fine. But Queasar not. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Any reason why you are using v-model and @input on the same input?
You can do this just by using @input="SearchPeople" :value = "search"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the v-model and instead use `@input=searchPeople` and `:value= "search"`.
In the method I would then only change one thing i-e `this.search`

```
methods: {
        searchPeople() {
            console.log('teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest');
            this.loading = true;
            this.search = event.target.value // This would add the value entered in the input
            api.get('https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people?search' + this.search)
                .then( result => {
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .catch( error => {

                })
                .then( () => {
                    this.loading = false
                });
            },
    }
```

Comment: I think v-modal is same to :value.

Comment: Its a good practice not to use v-model and v-on:input on the same element I believe. 
I would either just use v-model or simply use @input & :value only

Comment: Oh Awesome, I like to meet new people.

Comment: And also Like Vue expert, I also have 5 years of vue experience. so Can we meet often to discuss about Some codes?

Comment: If possible, give me your mail address,

Comment: Does v-model block @input event? I thing it does not matter and I need it.

Comment: @input=searchPeople does not call the function. What is wrong with that. @change works well but it is not what I need.Is it Quasar?

Comment: In Vuejs v-model is the same as "v-on: input=" & ":value="
So technically you are using v-on:input twice by adding v-model to the same <input>
Try with v-on:change in my solution and I'm sure it will work. Other than that if you have any other reasons to use v-on:input twice in the form of v-model and v-on:input then kindly mention it

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I need to call some action on input change I should make computed method? Cause I need to react on the event. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <q-input outlined v-model="search" v-on:change="searchPeople()" name="search" label="Name" />
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <q-input outlined v-model="search" @change="searchPeople()" name="search" label="Name" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is change the same as input? Cause in pure html it is not.

Comment: Or I think you can update your code to second case.

Comment: Second? It is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, the only detail I see is the **searchStatus** variable is not defined, that maybe is doing your code get a error. I tested on my local and it works

Comment: This was answered last week, and that answer was accepted.